# How start apache in centOS 7

Tags: linux, apache, centos7

I was starting Apache using this command : `service httpd start` in `centOS6`

Today I did download `centOS7-64bit-minimal` and wanted to start Apache after installing this.

When I use `service httpd start`, os will show me a message says:

> Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start httpd.service

Should I use `[root@localhost#] /bin/systemctl start httpd.service`??

I tried `[root@localhost#] systemctl start httpd.service` and it seems it's OK, but in the `centOS6`, there was starting status with something like `[OK]` or `[FAILED]` after starting `httpd` or something like that, but in this version, there is no report...

Am I in right way?

 Is httpd started correctly after this command :

`[root@localhost#] systemctl start httpd.service` ?

***Thanks in advance...***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Systemd! This has replaced `service` in recent Red Hat ilk, such as CentOS 7. You are on the right track with `systemctl`. Now, instead of checking logs in `/var/log/messages/`, you use `journalctl` to view logs. To look at logs specific to “httpd”, you can look at the “unit” with:

```
journalctl -u httpd
```

Other useful things to do with `journalctl`:

```
alias jc='journalctl -xa'  # make a friendly alias for ease of typing
jc -f  # follow the current events
```

Answer (score 5):

you are doing it right. 
It sends your command to httpd service. You can use this command to see status of last command sent:

```
service httpd status
```

Answer (score 0):

Triggering the httpd service start must be changed..
Suggested way:

> systemctl start httpd.service

This would help in Linux EC2 instances..
Helped me though