# Start Apache server (httpd)

Tags: apache, unix, centos7

I am running the following command to start my apache server however it is not working.

```
systemctl start httpd
```

I get the following error message but am confused on what to do.

> Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with
>   error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe"
>   for details.

Comment: So what does `systemctl status httpd.service` and `journalctl -xe` reveal?

Comment: Please refer to question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32021476/how-start-apache-in-centos-7?rq=1